# After enabling Cost Allocation Tags they don't appear in cost explorer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have had some EC2 instances running for many months but recently I started using AWS Cost Explorer. The instances already had tags on them i.e. "Env", "AppName". After I activated these tags in the Cost Allocation Tags section I still dont see them in the Cost Explorer filters. How long does it take for them to show up in the cost explorer filters or am I doing something wrong? I know for linked accounts it takes up to 7 days but this is not a linked account it is the actual account with my instances in it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the AWS documentation on [Using Cost Allocation Tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html):

> All tags can take up to 24 hours to appear in the Billing and Cost Management console.

Comment: It actually took quite a bit longer for mine to show up, I think it took like 4 days. Basically you just have t be patient.

Comment: Yep, they took a couple of days of so to turn up for me, too.

Answer (score 2):

Try a different Date Range (more recent), e.g. "last 7 days", this worked for me.

Comment: thanks after waiting 24 hours for tags to show up, and filtering for a recent date range, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe AWS docs' 24 hour delay. Mine took 3 days. So, you've just got to wait. AWS crew, if you're reading this, fix this up please!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this helps, but just checking. Have you checked the "Cost allocation report" option under your Billing->Preferences->Report section (under "Receive Billing Reports") ?

Answer (score -1):

For User defined tags you need to name them with prefixes.

i.e : "user:Env" , "Appname"